# Validate many-to-many circle

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this object association here:

```
Entry *--1 Category *--1 Project *--* User 1--* Entry
```

Explanation: An entry belongs to a category which has many entries, a category belongs to a project which has many categories - many users can have many projects. This user also has many entries and one entry belongs to one user.

When an entry is saved with a category and user association, I want to make sure, that the category belongs to a project a user is assigned to.

I thought about implementing a custom validator that fetches the project of the worklog and checks if it's in the list of the user's projects.

Is there a more Rails-like way to it or am I on the right track?

Comment: I'm not sure what "rails-like" way means. But a custom validator is certainly an option I would consider.

Comment: Yes, seems so. I mean that in Rails everything very lightweight and sophisticated with little custom code for most tasks etc., if you know what I mean.